# Grafana clickhouse

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I'm new in grafana, so I have a question.

I have a datasource in clickhouse, and I add it to grafana. Everything is ok.
However, when I try to create a graph I have problems. The type of my ColDateTime is string, so grafana does not understand that its my date. I will tell from the start I do not want to change it.

My datasource is like

```
mess_id | date       | datetime(typestring)
1233243 | 2019-09-19 | '2019-09-19 15:15:15'
```

The question is: what should I do for grafana to understand me without macroses?And how to build the request.

P.S.Try to answer cause I read almost everything about grafana-clickhouse.

Thanks very much for quick and full answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can create VIEW and use it in Grafana

```
create view table_v as 
select mess_id, 
       date, 
       toDateTime(datetime)*1000 timestamp_ms
from table
```